# How do I get arrows that look like this?

Tags: symbols, arrows

How do I get arrows that look like this?
It should look like a two headed `\Longrightarrow`.

[image: arrow1]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem exactly? That is, what is it about these arrows which you need but can't find? In what context do you need to use them? Have you looked in the comprehensive list's section on arrows? Considered TikZ?

Comment: Hand made weird iff `\newcommand*\wiff{\mathrel{\prec\mkern-6mu\Longleftrightarrow\mkern-6mu\succ}}`. Not exactly, but may be a first approach (avoiding designing it manually with `pict2e`).

Comment: What I need is something that looks similar to \Longrightarrow, but is different, so that the two can be distinguished. I have tried similar things to what Manuel is recommending (i.e. using \succ) but I am not happy with those.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Manuel suggested combining `\prec` and `\succ` with `\Longleftrightarrow`, but the OP was not happy with the appearance of such.  I thus took that as a challenge to try to improve the look.  I hopefully succeed by stretching the `\prec` and `\succ` glyphs horizontally and also trimming off the extra long tips.  Then I make it work in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx,trimclip,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*\wiffts{\scalebox{1.3}[1]{\clipbox{3pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$\prec$}}%
  \kern-4.4pt\mbox{$\Longleftrightarrow$}\kern-4.4pt%
  \scalebox{1.3}[1]{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 3.3pt 0pt}{$\succ$}}}
\newcommand*\wiff{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\wiffts}{\succ}}}
$a \wiff b$\par
$\scriptstyle a \wiff b$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle a \wiff b$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making my own version (using rotated and shifted versions of `\curlywedge`) with which I am fairly happy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\newcommand*\wif{= \joinrel = \joinrel = \mkern-2.3mu \joinrel \mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\curlywedge$}}}
\joinrel \mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\curlywedge$}}}}
\newcommand*\wiff{\mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\curlywedge$}}}
\joinrel \mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\curlywedge$}}} \mkern-5mu =\joinrel = \joinrel = \mkern-2.3mu \joinrel \mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\curlywedge$}}}
\joinrel \mathrel{\raisebox{0.5pt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\curlywedge$}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \wiff b$\par
$a \wif b$
\end{document}
```

[image]